# react-native upgrade caused issue with performance

Tags: react-native, upgrade

I have upgraded react-native from 0.27.2 to 0.39.2. Now my app works extremely slow,  transition takes about 5 second to complete. A drawer does not even open.  I have this issue on both: emulator and real device. Before upgrade everything worked perfect.

Comment: Have you tried 0.40? Have you tried with debugging disabled?

Comment: Well, I've tried 0.40 - it's the same.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with both 0.39.2 and 0.40.0.

Comment: I have an infinite scroll list with relatively heavy data and as soon as I load >15 items it slows down a lot. Only the javascript thread is affected. Naitve UI and native animations remain smooth.
@SergeyOnishchenko try 0.38.0, as I suspect the new CSS implementation in 0.39.2 is responsible.

Comment: Seems to be a big with RN itself. [Relative issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11809)

Comment: Downgrading to 0.39.0 - did not produce any changes, so did 0.38.0